# Infiniband switch, uplink

Tags: networking, ethernet, infiniband

Regarding switches like Mellanox Voltaire VLT-30011 (QDR IB, managed). I see a gigabit ethernet port on the switch which in the manual (http://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_ib_switch_systems/4036_2036_Installation_Manual.pdf) is labeled "for management", but it's also the uplink I take it? My intention is for one of the nodes in my cluster to act as login node, being reachable from the Internet.

I have seen BridgeX switches with "integrated ethernet gateways", but my interpretation of this is that the switch can handle ethernet (protocol) communication internally as well?

Comment: Just put an ethernet card into the node that also needs IP.  It could also act as a router and you can run IPoIB if required.  Some of those switches can run dual protocol ethernet + infiniband.  I'm not sure if this is one of those.  Talk to your Mellanox rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VLT-30011 the GigE interface is for management access only.

You need both IPoIB running on all InfiniBand nodes and either a BridgeX gateway or a  node with an Ethernet card configured to act as a router as Matt suggested in the comments.

The BridgeX VPI enabled VLT-30037 was probably the closest Voltaire switch to what you are asking for.